# Static static resources going through DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

In my Spring webapp I have annotated my dispatcher servlet like this:

```
  <tx:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.package.controller" />

    <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/script/" mapping="/script/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/img/" mapping="/img/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/fonts/" mapping="/fonts/**" />


    <!-- Uso de Tiles -->
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    </bean>
```

Now by activating spring's debug mode on log4j.properties, I've checked that every resource (even static resources) goes through DispatcherServlet, which I don't even know if it's expected behavior. The fact is, by debugging the processRequest method I've checked that this method is somehow causing high memory consumption on serving each webpage, my guess being that every static resource is being held in memory by this method.

This is the log output for a static resource such as jquery script library:

```
14:14:23,569 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Looking up handler method for path /script/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
14:14:23,575 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:230 - Did not find handler method for [/script/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js]
14:14:23,576 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:169 - Matching patterns for request [/script/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js] are [/script/**]
14:14:23,576 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:194 - URI Template variables for request [/script/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js] are {}
14:14:23,576 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:124 - Mapping [/script/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@101f75b5] and 1 interceptor
14:14:23,576 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:912 - Last-Modified value for [/myapp/script/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js] is: -1
14:14:23,576 DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler:173 - Trying relative path [jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js] against base location: ServletContext resource [/script/]
14:14:23,577 DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler:178 - Found matching resource: ServletContext resource [/script/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js]
14:14:23,577 DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler:132 - Determined media type 'application/javascript' for ServletContext resource [/script/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js]
```

As far as I can tell it's properly identifying it as a static resource.

Is my configuration right? Shouldn't static resources be served directly instead of going throuhg Dispatcher Servlet? Could it be that every resource is being kept in memory on serving it to the response?

Answer (score 3):

```
<mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" />
```

means that the dispatcher servlet will, indeed, serve static resources located in `/css` for any URL starting with `/css/`. This is what allows serving static resources from the classpath, for example, instead of serving them from static files in the webapp.

If you don't want the Spring servlet to serve static resources, the do as [the documentation indicates](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler):

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I put that in my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml config, will it automatically map the static resources to a default servlet? How does it interpret what is "static" and what is not?

Comment: Yes, it will. How does it do, I don't know. Either it first goes to the default servlet and then handles the request if the default servlet didn't find anything, or it does the inverse, or it checks if the static resource exists and forwards to the default servlet. You would have to dive in the sources to know.

Answer (score 1):

If you've done configured something with Spring, Spring will handle it.

When you provide a config with this element

```
<mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" />
```

Spring registers a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` bean with a mapping between the specified `mapping` and a `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` for the `location`.

The `DispatcherServlet` registers all `HandlerMapping` beans it finds in the `ApplicationContext`. One of these will be the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` above. If a request arrives which the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` can handle, the `DispatcherServlet` will use it. The `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` will then delegate to the appropriate `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` which will serve the static resource.

> Could it be that every resource is being kept in memory on serving it
>   to the response?

No, the `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` does not cache the content of the resource.

Comment: I understand that, but somehow this processing by DispatcherHandler (or whatever comes next) is eating my memory. What could the cause for that be?

Comment: @kelmer What evidence do you have for this? The `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` streams the content from the resource to the `ServletResponse` `OutputStream`, it doesn't cache anything.

Comment: I am using a memory profiler, and by debugging I see that after executing the "processRequest" method of DispatcherServlet, my memory gets loaded with an extra 30Mb. This happens every time I reload that page using Ctrl+F5 (thus avoiding local cache)

Comment: @kelmer Is the resource 30MB? Does that memory get garbage collected?

Comment: It goes up to that after going through every resource. They don't even amount to 30 mb (so I don't really know where the problem is), and they do are garbage collected o it's not a memory leak. But still is too high of a memory consumption. I am executing load tests with 10 simultaneous requests and that amounts for 300MB of memory load, which is too much IMO. And all this memory consumption gets accumulated in the succesive processRequest() calls from static resources.

Comment: @kelmer: the GC runs when it wants to. If you assigned X MBs of memory to the VM, then it shouldn't be a problem if the memory consumption goes up until X is reached. And since the memory is garbage-collected, then there isn't any leak. If you don't want so much memory to be consumeed by the JVM, then decrease the max size of the heap.

Comment: That does not solve my problem; my load test requirements include the GC not executing too often (probably to save CPU cycles). I need to reduce memory usage, even if this memory usage is not caused by a memory leak.

Comment: @kelmer You can debug the request handling. The `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`. The source code is also available if you need it. It doesn't create that many objects and it streams the content, so it never needs to have it all in memory at the same time. There might be something else in play here.

Comment: Reduce the memory usage, and have the GC not run too often are quite contradictory. If you want few GC, then you shouldn't care about the memory usage rising between expected limits. If you want low memory usage, then you need the GC to run often.